# Особенности переменной в callback-функциях JavaScript

Tags: node.js, javascript, mongoose

Проблема такая:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
  var user = new User({
    username: "Tester2",
    password: "secret",
    login: "asd"
  });
  user.save(function(err, user, affected) {
    if (err) throw err;
    User.findOne({username: "Tester2"}, 'login', function (err, tester) {
      data = {user: tester.login};
    });
  });
  res.render('index', data);
});
```

Хотелось бы делать рендер страницы именно в этом месте, но в таком случае `data` получается неидентифицированным. Работает, только если рендер поместить непосредственно в функции поиска. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то не так давно работаю с `JavaScript`, поэтому не могу понять все особенности языка. Использую `Node.js` и модуль `mongoose` и шаблонизатор `ect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операция записи в базу данных - асинхронная, так что рендер нужно звать по факту её завершения.
В простейшем случае так:

```
  user.save(function(err, user, affected) {
    if (err) throw err;
    User.findOne({...}, null, function (err, tester) {
         res.render('index', {user: tester.login});
    });
  });
```

Comment: кстати, я думаю, что User.findOne тут вообще не нужен...